# Querying friends for a user based on self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table and a self-referencing table so users can be assigned as friends to each other. The table looks like this:

[image: Database model - Image.frl - free image hosting]
<sub>(source: [image.frl](https://image.frl/i/366yhjhkqxyvl8mo.png))</sub>

I want to query the table and get back all the friends for a particular user (for example by user id). I'm not sure how to query it in a way that it knows that it should look for all the friend id's for the user id and lookup all the users that are associated with those friend id's in the user table.

Can anyone shed a light on how this can be done? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I don't think that "user_has_friends" is a good name for a DB table..

Comment: Do you just want first generation friendships, or do you also want e.g. friends of friends?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Any suggestions what a good naming strategy would be for associate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question (a look up by user_id) is this

```
SELECT friends.*
FROM user AS friends
JOIN user_has_friends ON friends.id = user_has_friends.friend_id
WHERE user_has_friends.user_id = *ID HERE*
```

You'd have to add another join to the users table if you wanted to look up by first_name or any other column.